# Issue in Shopping cart using Jquery

Tags: jquery, cart

I'm designing a shopping cart. In this cart functionality for first product is working fine but I'm facing an issue in the second product. Can somebody suggest/help me with this. Please have a look at the fiddle link mentioned below.
Moreover, this cart is working fine with the single product but with multiple products, it is not working.

Here is HTML

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
           <div class="shopping-cart">
              <div class="column-labels">
                 <label class="product-image">Image</label>
                 <label class="product-details">Product</label>
                 <label class="product-price">Price</label>
                 <label class="product-quantity">Quantity</label>
                 <label class="product-removal">Remove</label>
                 <label class="product-line-price">Total</label>
              </div>
              <div class="product">
                 <div class="product-image">
                 </div>
                 <div class="product-details">
                    <div class="product-title">Test Product</div>
                    <p class="product-description">Lorem ipsum dolor...</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="product-price">100</div>
                 <div class="product-quantity">
                    <div class="button-container">
                       <button class="cart-qty-plus" type="button" value="+">+</button>
                       <button class="cart-qty-minus" type="button" value="-">-</button>
                       <input type="number" value="1" min="1" class="qty" disabled>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="product-removal">
                    <button class="remove-product">
                    Remove
                    </button>
                 </div>
                 <div class="product-line-price">100</div>
              </div>
              <div class="product">
                 <div class="product-image">
                 </div>
                 <div class="product-details">
                    <div class="product-title">Test product2</div>
                    <p class="product-description">Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
                 </div>
                 <div class="product-price">100</div>
                 <div class="product-quantity">
                    <div class="button-container">
                       <button class="cart-qty-plus" type="button" value="+">+</button>
                       <button class="cart-qty-minus" type="button" value="-">-</button>
                       <input type="number" value="1" min="1" class="qty" disabled>
                    </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="product-removal">
                    <button class="remove-product">
                    Remove
                    </button>
                 </div>
                 <div class="product-line-price">100</div>
              </div>
              <div class="totals">
                 <div class="totals-item">
                    <label>Subtotal</label>
                    <div class="totals-value" id="cart-subtotal">71.97</div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="totals-item">
                    <label>Tax (5%)</label>
                    <div class="totals-value" id="cart-tax">3.60</div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="totals-item">
                    <label>Shipping</label>
                    <div class="totals-value" id="cart-shipping">15.00</div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="totals-item totals-item-total">
                    <label>Grand Total</label>
                    <div class="totals-value" id="cart-total">90.57</div>
                 </div>
              </div>
              <button class="checkout">Checkout</button>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Here is Script

```
var taxRate = 0.05;
var shippingRate = 15.00;
var fadeTime = 300;



$(document).ready(function() {
    recalculateCart();
});


//On click Plus button

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cart-qty-plus").click(function() {
        var $n = $(this)
            .parent(".button-container")
            .parent(".product-quantity")
            .find(".qty");

        $n.val(Number($n.val()) + 1);

        updateQuantity(this);

    });
});


// On click minus button


$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".cart-qty-minus").click(function() {
        var $n = $(this)
            .parent(".button-container")
            .parent(".product-quantity")
            .find(".qty");

        var amount = Number($n.val());
        if (amount > 1) {
            $n.val(amount - 1);

            updateQuantity(this);

        }
    });
});



// If the removed button is clicked


$('.product-removal button').click(function() {
    removeItem(this);
});


/* Recalculate cart */

function recalculateCart() {
    var subtotal = 0;

    /* Sum up row totals */

    $('.product').each(function() {
        subtotal += parseFloat($(this).children('.product-line-price').text());

    });

    /* Calculate totals */

    var tax = subtotal * taxRate;
    var shipping = (subtotal < 300 ? shippingRate : 0);
    var total = subtotal + tax + shipping;

    /* Update totals display */
    $('.totals-value').fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {
        $('#cart-subtotal').html(subtotal.toFixed(2));
        $('#cart-tax').html(tax.toFixed(2));
        $('#cart-shipping').html(shipping.toFixed(2));
        $('#cart-total').html(total.toFixed(2));
        if (total == 0) {
            $('.checkout').fadeOut(fadeTime);
        } else {
            $('.checkout').fadeIn(fadeTime);
        }
        $('.totals-value').fadeIn(fadeTime);
    });
}


/* Update quantity */

function updateQuantity(quantityInput) {
    /* Calculate line price */

    var productRow = $(quantityInput).parent().parent().parent();
    var price = parseFloat(productRow.children('.product-price').text());



    var quantity = $(".qty").val();



    var linePrice = price * quantity;

    /* Update line price display and recalc cart totals */

    productRow.children('.product-line-price').each(function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(fadeTime, function() {
            $(this).text(linePrice.toFixed(2));
            recalculateCart();
            $(this).fadeIn(fadeTime);
        });
    });
}


/* Remove item from cart */
function removeItem(removeButton) {
    /* Remove row from DOM and recalc cart total */
    var productRow = $(removeButton).parent().parent();
    productRow.slideUp(fadeTime, function() {
        productRow.remove();
        recalculateCart();
    });
}
```

Here is [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lb430o8/) link

Comment: `var price = parseFloat(productRow.children('.product-price').text());` will always fetch the first item's price. You should use a whole another strategy to display items on your shopping cart. An array of objects (items) should do the trick. That's the proper way to scale.

Comment: Can you please suggest a little bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to using .closest() method to element near clicked element.
https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 2):

only change this line:

```
 var quantity = $(".qty").val();
```

to

```
 var quantity = productRow.find(".qty").val();
```

---

[Test corrected fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1Lb430o8/18/)

Comment: Thank you so much. It is working fine now. Any further suggestion to improve code quality is most welcome.